# Como funciona para colocar conteúdo dinâmico fazendo um aplicativo para Android de forma nativa?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

Galera, estou vendo um pouco de desenvolvimento mobile (Android), e vi que o design é feito usando XML, e pelo que eu vi, parece não ter nenhuma tag de loop, para repeti estruturas semelhantes, e gerar algum conteúdo de forma dinâmica.

Como é que faria para fazer algo assim?

Um exemplo feito em React Navive:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={[
            {key: 'Devin'},
            {key: 'Jackson'},
            {key: 'James'},
            {key: 'Joel'},
            {key: 'John'},
            {key: 'Jillian'},
            {key: 'Jimmy'},
            {key: 'Julie'},
          ]}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlatListBasics);
```

A `<FlatList>` repete o array que é passado no atributo `"data"`

Comment: Coloque um exemplo concreto do que pretende fazer.

Comment: @ramaral, ainda não quero fazer nada, é só uma duvida. No Ionic tem o *ngFor do Angular, no React Native tem a FlatList, eu queria saber como faz algo semelhante de forma nativa no Android Studio.

Comment: No Android "nativo" tem de usar Java ou Kotlin para manipular o conteúdo das views.

Comment: Então tem como desenhar a interface usando somente java? Tem como você explicar mais? Não precisa de código não.

Comment: No Android você faz isso através do componente `RecyclerView` em conjunto com um `Adapter`, pesquise sobre esses termos

Comment: *"Então tem como desenhar a interface usando somente java?"* - Tem, mas normalmente essa não é a melhor abordagem. Se quer programar "nativamente" tem de "esquecer" o que sabe de React Native.

Comment: No nativo se tem um XML para a view-pai e um XML para o elemento que irá compor sua lista de itens. E no código Java esses dois XML são combinados programaticamente. Estou certo ou enferrujei demais? :)

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo uma pequena modificação no seu componente, os dados da **FlatList**, podem ficar dinâmicos.

Setando uma variável no **state** do componente, é possível referenciar ele no método **render()**, assim a lista pode mudar de acordo com o conteúdo da variável **data_list**. Inclusive se ela for alterada, o **FlatList** será atualizado.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class FlatListBasics extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      data_list: [
        {key: 'Devin'}, {key: 'Jackson'},
        {key: 'James'}, {key: 'Joel'},
        {key: 'John'}, {key: 'Jillian'},
        {key: 'Jimmy'}, {key: 'Julie'},
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          data={ this.state.data_list }
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
   flex: 1,
   paddingTop: 22
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})

// skip this line if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => FlatListBasics);
```